# How to get a sublist of a list between two words

Tags: python, list, slice

Starting from a list like this:

```
words = ['tree', 'water', 'dog', 'soap', 'bike', 'cat', 'bird']
```

I want to get the sublist between two specified words. For example, if I have the words `'water'` and `'bike'` I want to get the sublist:

```
words = ['water', 'dog', 'soap', 'bike']
```

or if the list is

```
words = ['tree', 'water', 'dog', 'soap', 'tree', 'cat', 'bird']
```

and I put the words `'tree'` and `'tree'` I want to get this sublist:

```
words = ['tree', 'water', 'dog', 'soap', 'tree']
```

I have also written a program like this in C, but I'm not very good with Python at the moment.
This is my C version:

```
struct node {
    char *key;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
typedef struct node node;

node *GetSublist(node *, char *, char *);
node *MakeStringList();
void PrintStringList(node *a);

node *GetSublist(node *a, char *k1, char *k2) {

    node *p = a;
    node *n1, *n2;

    while (strcmp(p->key, k1) != 0) {
        p = p->next;
        if (p == NULL) {
            return a;
        }
    }

    n1 = p;
    n2 = p->next;

    if (n1->prev != NULL) {
        while (a != n1) {
            free(a);
            a = a->next;
        }
    }
    a->prev = NULL;

    while (strcmp(n2->key, k2) != 0) {
        n2 = n2->next;
        if (n2 == NULL) {
            return a;
        }
    }

    if (n2->next != NULL) {
        while (n2->next == NULL) {
            free(n2->next);
            n2 = n2->next;
        }
        n2->next = NULL;
    }

    return a;
}

int main(){

    char *k1 = "dog";
    char *k2 = "ball";
    node *list1 = NULL;
    list1 = MakeStringList();
    PrintStringList(list1);
    list1 = GetSublist(list1, k1, k2);
    PrintStringList(list1);


return 0;
}

node *MakeStringList() {             
    node *a = NULL, *punt, *p;
    int i;
    int dim;

    printf("Number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &dim);

    for (i=0; i<dim; i=i+1) {
        punt = malloc( sizeof(node) );
        punt->key = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
        scanf( "%s", punt->key );
        punt->next = NULL;
        punt->prev = NULL;
        if(a == NULL) {
            a = punt;
            p = punt;
        } else {
            p->next = punt;
            punt->prev = p;
            p = punt;
        }
    }
return a;
}

void PrintStringList(node *a) {                   
    node *p = a;
    printf("\nThe list is: { ");
    while( p != NULL ) {
        if (p->next == NULL)
            printf("%s ", p->key);
        else
        printf("%s, ", p->key);
        p = p->next;

    }
    printf("}\n\n");
}
```

Comment: So `words[words.index('water'):words.index('bike')+1]`? What if words appear multiple times, or in a different order?

Comment: This should be a fairly easy task (using `list.index(word)` and list slicing).  Can you show us what you've attempted that isn't working?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's not a problem if words appear multiple times, in that case sublist starts with the first word and ends with the last of that word.

Thank you

Comment: @mgilson Still i didn't know the .index() method, i'm beginning with Python.

Thank you for help

Comment: @Frepard you may say *"It's not a problem"*, but `.index` gives you the **first** index of that value!

Answer (score 5):

This can be accomplished with the `.index()` method of lists, and with the slice notation..

```
words = ['tree', 'water', 'dog', 'soap', 'cat', 'bird']
start_index = words.index(start_word)
end_index = words.index(end_word)
sublist = words[start_index:end_index+1]
```

Comment: Be careful with start_index and end_index acting on the same word (like tree), in this example they'll both incorrectly evaluate to the same value.
Perhaps some variation of  end_index =  len(words) - 1 - words[::-1].index('tree') would be prudent

Comment: @HexedAgain in that case, i can use the index of the next word (like cat). It's right?

Comment: Well you could, I suppose - if for any list with two interesting values you always know which word follows the last then you're good to go. If you can't guarantee this however then, as per my quick example you may be better served finding the first index in a reversed list (which would of course be the last index in the non-reversed list)

Answer (score 1):

```
def sublist_two_words(array, start_word, end_word):
    result = []
    for word in array:
        if result or word == start_word:
            result.push(word)
        if word == end_word:
            break
    return result
```

This way even if there is not `end_word` it gets the whole remaining list. If I got correctly your task.